# How to report error if redirect_uri doesn't match?

Tags: oauth2, url-redirection, openid-connect

How should the auth server (IDP) report the error if the authorisation request `redirect_uri` doesn't match the configured `redirect_uri` for the given client?

Let's consider concrete example:

- `auth.com` is the IDP
- `service.com` if the registered `redirect_uri`
- `service.io` if passed in the authorisation request

Should the auth server:

1. stay on `auth.com` and show error?
2. redirect to `service.com/?error=xxx`?
3. redirect to `service.io/?error=xxx`?

Option 1. seems secure, but UX is subpar — the auth server can only render generic failure that end user cannot do anything about, the requestor doesn't get an error notification and end user cannot try some other authentication method if there were multiple choices

Option 2. seems secure but a bit odd, possibly leaving end user confused (if real and fake sites look same), and I wonder if there's an attack vector I didn't think of...

Option 3. seems quite insecure, certainly auth server should not be redirecting end user to `http://localhost` or `ftp://` or `fb.com/post/new`, but it does allow for the misconfigured service to learn about the error. I feel that's especially important if the service is e.g. a mobile app with custom URI scheme.

I've skimmed through OAuth 2.0 and OIDC Core specs and so far couldn't figure this out. A canonical answer would be grand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2.1), you should display an error message on the authorization server (option 1):

> If the request fails due to a missing, invalid, or **mismatching**
> **redirection URI**, or if the client identifier is missing or invalid,
> the authorization server SHOULD inform the resource owner of the
> error and **MUST NOT automatically redirect** the user-agent to the
> **invalid redirection URI.**

Answer (score 0):

There's another, indirect statement about this case:

> Unless the Redirection URI is invalid, the Authorization Server
>   returns the Client to the Redirection URI specified in the
>   Authorization Request with the appropriate `error` and `state` parameters.
>   Other parameters SHOULD NOT be returned.

Source: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthError

I think this confirms @Tangui's answer.